# Fritzing part repositry - GY-30

Tags: pcb-design

There is no `GY-30` light sensor part design in the standard Fritzing repository.

[image]

Is there an official alternative part repository containing Fritzing `fzpz` file for this sensor?  Does it go by any other name or part code?

[image]

Comment: Design your own part. Or find some other I2C breakout in the fritzing library that has the same pinout. Or use a 5 pin header instead.

Comment: a bit time consuming, and i'm sure that there is something out there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part also goes by the name `BH1750`.  And that is available in the Fritzing  parts library.

Comment: This is the correct one : http://goo.gl/JiTmQt  it is called BH1750FVI Breakout Board (GY-30). The bare BH1750 has a different pin order.

Comment: thanks for reviving this.  i've been using the GY-302.  I'll give this part a look, tks!!!!